# Will Canadian Motion Controller work in EU PS3?

Tags: ps3, playstation-move

I have a European PS3 but I'm going to Canada in a couple days and wanted to know if the motion controllers from US will work on my PS3. They are A LOT cheaper there and in Portugal is nowhere easy to find them available to buy used...

Comment: The technology for controllers should be the same regardless of region.  I wouldn't see why not.

Comment: I don't really know how the controller communicates with the console to detect the button presses. The frequencies could be different...

Comment: They use bluetooth.  That's a universal standard.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my knowledge there is no difference in hardware devices, since we're not talking about the power supply or different tech standards like in mobile phones/networks. Therefore I guess you won't have any problem to get your PS3 to work with this device.

If you buy a new one from a shop keep in mind that you *may* have some trouble with the  sending in for repair.

Comment: and what about the communication frequencies? It could be different, no?

Comment: I thought that the regular gamepads communicate via bluetooth and so should the move-pad. Why should sony change this and further more, why should sony produce so many different devices for each country? You can change the powersupply easily, but the technology inside a gamepad? I don't think so, but I'm not *that* into sonys hardwareconcept :)